# Laravel Blade - yield inside section

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to yield a section inside another section. But this does not work as expected, I see blank output.

```
@section('3show')
        This is a text string
@stop

@section('page-content')

<div id="content">
    <article>

        @yield('3show')

    </article>
</div>
<!--#content-->


@stop
```

Any ideas to yield section inside another section ?

Comment: So are you getting a second blade template which extends from this file with a defined @section('3show'), you call that 2nd file and you are getting a blank page? Am I understanding right?

Comment: @JulianRodriguez yes !

Comment: @JulianRodriguez any ideas or some alternates ?

Comment: No, actually I have tried your example as it is a couple of minutes ago and it works pretty well. I replicated your problem defining @section('3show') after the @section('page-content'). I beleave this could be solved by defining your section before the page-content' definition and append to '3show' section all the code you need in your second file which extends of this template.

Comment: @JulianRodriguez I have tried in that way too, however it did not show up. So for time being, I'm using @include('partials') and I find it lame as I land up creating files for each partials. Ever since start, I've been wishing to have something like my example, so that I can have all my partials under one file and play with it easier.   Anyways thanks !

Comment: But that example actually works. My answer is something like the "right way" I suppose, but you could define all your partials in one blade template just defining as many sections as you wish, then yield them in the last defined section. To be honest, I dont like that way, but I have to say that it is actually possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, this is what I tried and I can confirm that this works, at least for Laravel 5+ (I have L5.2). This is how I suggest you to use your blade templates.

Lets start saying that to yield a section into another section you have to define your included section before container section definition. So, with that clear, I solved this situation like this:

I got a main blade (main.blade.php) template which has something like:

```
<section class="content">
 <!-- Your Page Content Here -->
 @yield('main-content')
</section><!-- /.content -->
```

I got a second blade (common.blade.php) template which has that common stuff you may want to show across many pages and where main-content section is defined. This one looks like:

```
@section('main-content')
  <div class="container">
    @yield('extra-content')
  </div>
@endsection
```

Finally I got a 3rd template (test.blade.php) which extend the main template and include the common stuff I want to show, but be careful because the order matters. This one looks like:

```
@extends('main')
@section('extra-content')
  <div>
    <span> This is a test! </span>
  </div>
@endsection
@include('common')
```

In your controller or your route (wherever you return your view), you should return the 3rd template.

Comment: P.S. My code that's in question didn't work on an older version of Laravel. I recently tried this on 5.4, the results were as expected.

Answer (score 5):

In my projects i create some partials in order to have cleaner code and i give them as an example a name : 3show.blade.php. In order to use them in a section i just include them. 
I think this will do what you want.

```
@section('content')
    @include('3show.blade.php')
@endsection
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

You can't use the @extends option in this case, you need to use @include .

So lets say you have:

1. the root layout (layouts/app.blade.php)
2. an extra layout (layouts/extra.blade.php)
3. the actual view that you are calling (someview.blade.php)

The solution is to use add/inherit the root layout (1) to the top line of your view (3):

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

Next, add/inherit the extra layout (2) to the second line of your view, BUT use @include not @extends:

```
@include('layouts.extra')
```

...and remember to wrap the content of your extra layout  in an @section name, for example *@section('extra')*

Finally you can call your extra layout content from your view:

```
  <p>Look below, you will see my extra content...</p>
  @yield('extra')
```

So in summary, your someview.blade.php view would look like:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@include('layouts.extra')

@section('content')
    <p>Look below, you will see my extra content...</p>
    @yield('extra')
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

solution 1:
you can use `@show` instead of `@stop` at the end of section
then laravel will render your `@yield`  parts ...

like this :

```
@section('page-content')

<div id="content">
    <article>

              @yield('3show')

    </article>
</div>  

@show  # not @stop




@section('3show')

        This is a text string
@stop
```

this way render you view and show result
so if you cll your section for twice then result will be shoed twice

solution 2:

insert call section before yiel it
like this :

```
 **first call section :**

@section('3show')

        This is a text string
@stop

**then define your section : 3show**


@section('page-content')

<div id="content">
    <article>

              @yield('3show')

    </article>
</div>  

@stop  **not @show**
```

Answer (score 0):

assume you have two files:

-article_base.blade.php -> the default data in every article.

-article_index.blade.php -> the customized file.

```
article_base.blade.php
@extends('layout')
@section('page-content')

<div id="content">
    <article>
        ....
        @yield('3show')
        ....
    </article>
</div>
<!--#content-->
@stop
```

article_index.blade.php

```
@extends('article_base')
@section('3show')
   This is a text string
@endsection
```

I hope this works

Answer (score 0):

You have to both @include and @yield the child template in your main template to be able to add the child template at a specific place inside the main template (not just before or after the main template - this is done by adding @parent in the child template - but in between):

*main.blade.php*

```
@include('child')
<div>
     ...
     @yield('child')
</div>
```

*child.blade.php*

```
@section('child')
     <div>
          ...
     </div>
@endsection
```